# Dialect using "woman" instead of "women"?

Tags: pronunciation, dialects, accent, australian-english, new-zealand-english

If you watch [this VICE episode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fB2XRK_Xb6g), the presenter sounds like a native speaker, but uses "woman" instead of "women" every time (probably over a dozen times in the 10 minute video).

Specifically, the presenter is either *pronouncing* the word "women" in an unusual way (so: **is this some kind of dialect or regional variation?**) or he's *using* the singular "woman" when the plural "women" would be expected (in which case: **is there a reason for such usage? Or, if we can't fathom the reporter's reasons, is there precedent for this?**).

Examples:

@1:27:

> You might have expected the police at these marches to protect the woman

@2:08:

> for defending civilization, from woman he branded "barbarians"

@7:13:

> as well as the increased restrictions on woman's rights

Comment: That's just how Australians say 'women'.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it makes us watch a video.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey You are not allowed to include a link to a video to illustrate speech? Link to this rule please.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey There's no prohibition on linking to a video or sound recording to illustrate how a word is pronounced: how else do you provide an example? If that's why the question was closed, then this was in error: the question is entirely reasonable, since the reporter is either *pronouncing* the word "women" in an unusual way (so: is it a regional variation?) or *using* the singular "woman" when the plural "women" would be expected (so: is there a reason for such usage? Or, if we can't fathom the reporter's reasons, is there precedent for this?). ...

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - Unclear if you were joking, but I agree with Chappo HFM that that is definitely not how Australians pronounce *women*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR: this might be a New Zealand pronunciation.**

The presenter, Tim Hume, certainly has an intriguing mix of accents. His [bio](https://www.linkedin.com/in/tim-hume-8b171531/) doesn't say where he grew up, but I'm guessing he might have spent some childhood years in Australia, as there's a hint of an Australian accent. The bio also says he studied and worked in New Zealand 1998-2011 and has spent the last decade in Hong Kong and London. So, there are multiple possibilities for particular regional variations or dialects, either in pronunciation or usage.

One [comment on the question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/570410/dialect-using-woman-instead-of-women#comment1418321_570410) says "That's just how Australians say 'women'." I'm an Aussie and I can say categorically that this is NOT how Australians say 'women'.

However, it IS possible that the video clip reflects a **broad New Zealand pronunciation** of this word, in which the vowel sound in the first syllable of *women* changes from /ɪ/ to /ə/. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Zealand_English) gives the following relevant description:

> Non-rhotic New Zealand English is most similar to Australian English
> in pronunciation, with some key differences. A prominent difference
> is the realisation of /ɪ/ (the KIT vowel): in New Zealand English this
> is pronounced as a schwa.

A broad New Zealand accent would therefore make the plural *women* sound very similar (to an outsider) to the singular *woman*, and it's likely that the presenter has acquired and retained this element of the New Zealand accent, even if it's otherwise mostly lost or hard to pick.

Comment: *" this is NOT how Australians say 'women'"* Are you talking about all Australian accents?

Comment: It doesn't seem very likely that a native speaker would switch from "women" to "woman" in adulthood, in my opinion.

Comment: @bobcat I've never heard an Australian say "women" in this way. If you can find evidence of it being a specific regional thing, by all means, share in an answer.

Comment: @GArthurBrown I'm not saying Chappo's wrong. Just trying to clarify the claim. Australia is big.

Comment: @bobcat broad Aussie & NZ accents are easily distinguishable, but living overseas can weaken the difference or even eliminate the accent altogether, which is why I *guess* at a "hint" of an Aussie accent; his pronunciation of 20 as "twenny" is very Australian, whereas a Kiwi might pronounce it "twinny". But I've listened again to the video, and I simply can't explain his pronunciation of "women": he pronounces other "i" words (eg "similar") with the /ɪ/ sound you'd expect rather than using the NZ /ə/. Maybe, instead, it's a *deliberate* usage: a VICE style, or personal political statement?

Comment: @bobcat and yes there are indeed regional variations within Australia, but you'd have to be *very* familiar with the "standard" accent to be able to pick them up. After living here 60 years I'm getting better at picking *strong* Sydney and Queensland accents, but it's impossible to differentiate "cultivated" speakers except by word choice, eg "port" for suitcase in Qld. No one **anywhere** in Australia pronounces "women" as "woman": they'd be laughed at. :-)

Comment: The US has some [weird dialects](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AIZgw09CG9E) that most people never encountered.